# iphone get back button text

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller

Sorry for the another newbie question.

I tried to get the back button text value in viewDidLoad but it always displays null when I navigate through controllers.

```
NSLog(@"-----------> %@ ", self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title);
```

How to get the back button text value?

Comment: I found the solution. Get all the view controllers from navigation controller. You can get the title from last but one view controller (lastButOneController.navigationItem.title). I did this viewWillAppear function.

Comment: Hi, if you put your comment as an answer to this question and then accept it, people know it's answered ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use 
`self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title :)!`